# Using Php Sdk in android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I want to build an app using php, Now the developer doc tells me to use Php_SDK_GoogleAppEngine and Python. The Doc says,Google App Engine PHP SDK- which includes a web server application that simulates the App Engine environment, and tools to deploy your application to the App Engine production environment.I think,I am missing some key points here with the use of SDK. Now, my questions are-

I already use the latest Android Studio which already has a built-in app engine local Dev Server with deployment feature, why do I need another?

Isnt there any way I can use PHP SDK in Android Studio ?

When Android Studio builds a google cloud module,it automatically builds A WEB CLIENT (or web front end) with servlet etc but I dont know servlet. Cant I build a web client IN ANDROID STUDIO with php,html,javascript,css ? if so,how?

Answer (score 1):

Android studio supports Java App Engine development.

If you want to do PHP dev for App Engine you'll need the PHP SDK which is a separate download.

The PHP SDK download contains a dev server, PHP binary and a few other bits, but not an IDE.

Whether Android studio supports the required language syntax highlighting etc I do not know.

PhpStorm, Sublime, Netbeans would be my recommended IDE choices - although Sublime is more of a (great) text editor on steroids.

PhpStorm has optional support for AppEngine specific features.